# When I call a method, why isn't the overridden method called?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, oop

My problem is that my method call function goes to the virtual method, not to the overridden one. I tried to inherit the class with the virtual method and when I debug it's nothing different. What is missing?

```
public class Engine
{
    protected virtual void ExecuteCommand(string[] inputParams)
    {
        switch (inputParams[0])
        {
            case "status":
                this.PrintCharactersStatus(this.characterList);
                break;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void CreateCharacter(string[] inputParams)
    {
    }

    protected virtual void AddItem(string[] inputParams)
    {
    }

    private void ReadUserInput()
    {
        string inputLine = Console.ReadLine();
        while (inputLine != string.Empty)
        {
            string[] parameters = inputLine
                .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            ExecuteCommand(parameters);
            inputLine = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

public class Program : Engine
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Engine engine = new Engine();
        engine.Run();
    }

    protected override void ExecuteCommand(string[] inputParams)
    {
        base.ExecuteCommand(inputParams);

        switch (inputParams[0])
        {
            case "create":
                this.CreateCharacter(inputParams);
                break;

            case "add":
                this.AddItem(inputParams);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating an instance of `Engine`, not `Program` - all you need to do is change the first line of `Main` to:

```
Engine engine = new Program();
```

The implementation to use is based on the execution-time type of the object on which the method is called - in your existing code, that's only ever `Engine.ExecuteCommand`, so the code in `Program` won't get called.